# Dash unit tests with dash_duo always result in TestingTimeoutError

Tags: unit-testing, plotly-dash

I recently started using Dash for developing web applications. In order to improve the quality of my code, I began writing unit tests for these applications.

I followed the tutorials in the Dash documentation (https://dash.plotly.com/testing) and installed ChromeDriver and all other needed dependencies.  When running the example unit tests from the Dash Documentation, every test that used dash_duo failed with a TestingTimeoutError. The unit tests that don't use dash_duo run just fine, but every single test that uses dash_duo fails with a TestingTimeoutError.

Eventually, I wrote a super simple test:

```
import dash
from dash import html

def test_001_test_dash_duo(dash_duo):
    x = 2
    assert x == 2
```

Even this test fails with a timeout error:

```
msg = 'expected condition not met within timeout'

    def until(
        wait_cond, timeout, poll=0.1, msg="expected condition not met within timeout"
    ):  # noqa: C0330
        res = wait_cond()
        logger.debug(
            "start wait.until with method, timeout, poll => %s %s %s",
            wait_cond,
            timeout,
            poll,
        )
        end_time = time.time() + timeout
        while not res:
            if time.time() > end_time:
>               raise TestingTimeoutError(msg)
E               dash.testing.errors.TestingTimeoutError: expected condition not met within timeout
```

Any ideas of what is needed to get Dash unit tests using dash_duo to not fail by timeout?

Comment: Did you ever reach a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and the solution that worked for me was to add my web driver executable to my system environment PATH.

1. Download your web driver (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) -- looks like you already did this in your case.
2. Add the location of the executable for your driver to your system PATH (C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32) [or wherever you placed it]
3. Restart your terminal and run `pytest`.

In my case, this worked.